# Handlebars causes a Bootstrap table in a 2 column view to scroll the whole page instead of just the table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js

sorry if the question is confusing, I just started learning HTML and CSS a couple days ago.

I'm trying to build a side by side view that is 100% of the page height. The left side is a table that will show objects hosted on a server.

I have it working as I want but as soon as I add the handlebars script line `<script id="account-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">` the whole page starts scrolling instead of just the left table.

```
<script id="account-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="container-fluid full-height">
      <div class="row full-height">
        <div class="col-md-4 list-group full-height">
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">name</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">description</p>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">name</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">description</p>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">name</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">description</p>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">name</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">description</p>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">name</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">description</p>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">name</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">description</p>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">name</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">description</p>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">name</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">description</p>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">name</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">description</p>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">name</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">description</p>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">name</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">description</p>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">name</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">description</p>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item">
              <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">name</h4>
              <p class="list-group-item-text">description</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <center>.col-lg-6</center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, .full-height {
height: 100%;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: May be post more codes and JavaScript also from which you generate HTML using this template? That way we could create/run your code and see what can be done!

Comment: Using an id instead of a class made the css work. Can anybody explain why that would be?